# How to organize ids for resources in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In our model file, both participants and assets are identified by an id. When we are creating new instances of these, we are required to give it an id. like

```
var newAsset = getFactory().newResource(org.biznet,'ourAsset',assetID);
```

My question is how do we organize the IDs for our assets. I want the assets in ourAsset registry to be in some kind of order like 1,2,3 and I want to automate that so that every time a new ourAsset is being created it reads the id of the previous entry in the registry and increments it by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger dont have an auto-increment logic.
You should create your own logic.

However I sugest you to use hash instead of auto-increment.

There is a lib in Nodejs for that: `uuid`